# Don't understand why the constructor is called twice

Tags: c++

I'm new to c++(and programming) and I made this code:

main:

```
int main(){
  aircraft_list<planes> plane_list;
  plane_list.add();
}
```

constructor for planes:

```
planes::planes(){
  //initializing some vars
}
```

add():

```
template <class T> aircraft_list<T>& aircraft_list<T>::add(){
  chain_node<T> *y=new chain_node<T>;
  planes obj;
  y->data=obj;
  y->link=first;
  first=y;
  return *this;
}
```

constructor of aircraft_list:

```
aircraft_list(){
    first=0;
  }
```

destructor of aircraft_list:

```
template <class T> aircraft_list<T>::~aircraft_list(){
  chain_node<T> *next;
  while(first){
    next=first->link;
    delete first;
    first=next;
  }
}
```

From previous question I looked into the rule of three and fixed a problem with the destructor but still I can't understand why the constructor is called twice...Also when I comment out:

```
planes obj;
y->data=obj;
```

Constructor is called once...what happens to the object it creates?

**EDIT:**

```
aircraft_list class:

template <class T>
class aircraft_list{
friend class planes;

public:
  aircraft_list(){
    first=0;
  }
  ~aircraft_list();
  int search(const T &x) const;
  aircraft_list<T>& del(const T &x);
  aircraft_list<T>& add();

private:
  chain_node<T> *first;
};
```

chain_node class:

```
template <class T> class aircraft_list;
template <class T> class chain_node{

public:
  T data;
  chain_node<T> *link;
};
```

Comment: don't use new and a custom list

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: well I make this for an assignment and I must create one

Comment: When you call plane_list.add();
 a constructor for new object runs in add() function

Comment: It would help if you provided the class definitions, too.  I can't be sure from what you've posted, but I would guess that `chain_node<T>`'s constructor creates a `T`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put: you have at least two objects of airplane.

One is defined on

```
  planes obj;
```

This is easy to spot.
The other is a bit harder, and it's in a bit of code that you actually dind't pasted here.

```
  chain_node<T> *y = new chain_node<T>;
```

because your chain_node has a data of type T, and T is of type planes, when you create one chain_node, and chain_node has a planes on it's structure body, it will also create a new instance of planes.